# What is the correct way to extract a vector from a matrix in Eigen?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I'm a beginner in Eigen, and what I'm doing is to extract different rows from a matrix and do some calculation.

The code looks like this

```
MatrixXd mat(5, 10);
VectorXd vec1 = mat.row(1);
VectorXd vec2 = mat.row(2);
// do some calculation with vec1 and vec2
```

So the question is, by doing like `VectorXd vec = mat.row(1)`, there's memory allocation / memory copying which may be bad for performance. As I'm only using it for calculation and definitely won't do any changes to the matrix underneath, Is there a better way to do this?

I tried using `Eigen::Block` but it appeared that `Block` doesn't support some matrix operations (I'm not sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.row()` itself is not bad for performance at all, it is one of Eigen's block expressions.

> Blocks expressions can be used both as rvalues and as lvalues. As
>   usual with Eigen expressions, this abstraction has zero runtime cost
>   provided that you let your compiler optimize.

If you formulate your calculation in terms of expressions, the compiler can do all types of optimization.

Here is are some examples:

```
mat.row(2) = 2 * mat.row(0) + mat.row(1);
float x = (mat.row(0) - mat.row(1)).squaredNorm();
```

With this, you give enough information at compile time that Eigen can optimize.

Not sure what you mean with `Eigen::Block`, most common usage should be `.block()` of a matrix. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html